# Elasticsearch - Lsit whole object in terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I need to make a query that lists the whole objects in terms aggregation. The mapping is like this:

```
{
    "travelers": {
        "properties": {
            "traveler": "string",
            "cars": {
                "type":"nested",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    "color": {
                        "type":"string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the query I can make is like this:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "people": {
            "terms": {
                "field":"traveler"
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "cars": {
                "nested": {
                    "path":"cars"
                },
                "aggregations": {
                    "types": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field":"cars.type"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this query only returns the types of the cars. I can modify for it to return the types and the colors, but I can't, that way, tell which color is related to which type of car. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested aggregation simply makes sure that each nested object is treated as a document and aggregation happens on nested documents level and not on actual document level.

Hence you need to do one more level of aggregation with color to get what you are looking for.

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "people": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "traveler"
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "cars": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "cars"
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "types": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "cars.type"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "colors": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "cars.color"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```